# 'net stop spooler' fails with exit code 259

Tags: windows, winapi, error-code

I launch 'net stop spooler' using CreateProcess from my C++ program. It fails and the exit code is 259.

Anyone know what that error code means? Also if someone can give me a link to some documentation about the possible error codes for this command and their meanings I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean a subsequent GetExitCodeProcess call returns 259? Its STILL_ACTIVE meaning the process has not terminated, if CreateProcessFails (returns 0) what's GetLastError?

Comment: Yes, I call GetExitCodeProcess.

Comment: Then its not an error code, 259 means the process is still running so there is no exit code

Comment: Ok, thanks, could you post it as an answer, then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

259 is not an error rather its `STILL_ACTIVE` which `GetExitCodeProcess` returns if the process handle you pass it relates to a process that has not terminated (and so has no exit code).

If you want to wait for it to exit before getting the exit code, call `WaitForSingleObject()` on the process handle.

Comment: I've added a note explainign how to wait for it to exit which I assume they need.