# After port app WP7 to WP8 throws exception "The thread has exited...""

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

After port app WP7 to WP8  throws exceptions in output:

```
The thread 0xaac has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xabc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xad8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xb04 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xb0c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

But in emulator all works great. 
 Why these exceptions occur? 
 Will this work on real device?

Note: I use `WebClient`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't look like an exception, but a thread exit code (I'd guess probably due to a `ThreadPool` thread being ended). I see these extra lines in the Debug window and my app is working fine.

Comment: Yes, my app working fine to, but I can test it only on emulator. Did you test on the real device?

Comment: I just checked errors codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) . 259 (0x103) means
No more data is available. My app is running ok, but still wondering, what's going on inside.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko after seeing this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175430/net-stop-spooler-fails-with-exit-code-259) I think the number 259 should be interpreted as an exit code. According to [GetExitCodeThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation exit code 259 means that the thread is still active -- it is reasonable since the thread belongs to thread pool.